# variable length <td> IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `<table`> in a `<div`>.

Each row may contain one or two `<td`>

The first `<td`> will always contain some left justified text.

Rows with two `<td`> are disabled and clicking on them does nothing.

Rows with one `<td`> have an onClick function attached.

I want that one `<td`> to extend the entire width of the div so if you click anywhere within it (on the left justified text, on the blank part in the middle or at the far end on the right side) the onClick function will fire.

This works GREAT in Firefox.  When the page renders I can click anywhere in a row with a single `<td`> and the the onClick function will fire.  I verified this with console.log

In IE9 the only way I can get the onClick function to fire is to click *directly on the left justified text.*  Clicking anywhere else in that row DOES NOT execute the onClick function.  I've also verified this with console.log.  As near as I can tell, the `<td`> length is ONLY as big as the text within it (since only clicking on the text fires the onClick function)

What do i have to do to make IE9's behavior match Firefox's?

I'm using javascript to build the table and jQuery to display it by appending it to the div.

Some code:

```
<script>
  var tableString = '<table>';
  var tableArray=Array(10);

  for (i=0;i<tableArray.length; i++){
     tableArray[i] = one of the following strings

                     "<tr disabled><td> some text </td><td> more text </td></tr>"
                                                    or
                     "<tr onclick="clickFunc()" ><td> some text </td></tr>" 

     tableString = tableString + tableArray[i];     
  }

  tableString = tableString + '</table>';
  jQuery(#tableDiv).append(tableString);       
</script>

<body>
  <div id="tableDiv" width="600px" >
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please share some code with us.

Comment: Tip for the future: Use backticks ` to do inline code elements.

Comment: Assign the `onClick` to `div` instead of `td`

Comment: added code example, added back ticks

Comment: Kama - do you mean put a `<div`> in the `<td`>  ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 var tableString = '<table>';
  var tableArray=Array(10);

  for (i=0;i<tableArray.length; i++){
     tableArray[i] = "<tr disabled><td> some text </td><td> more text </td></tr>"
  // or "<tr onclick="clickFunc()" ><td> some text </td></tr>" 

     tableString = tableString + tableArray[i];     
  }

  tableString = tableString + '</table>';
  jQuery('#tableDiv').append(tableString);
```

jquery 1.10+

```
$('tr').attr('class','clicked');

$('tr').eq(2).text('number 3');

$('td').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('red')
});
```

css example

```
.red{
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: i'm not sure that i understand your answer.  My problem is the `<tr`> that looks like: `<tr onclick="clickFunc()" `>`<td`> some text `</td`>`</tr`> only fires the clickFunc() if i click exactly on "some text".  90% of that '<tr`> is blank.  i want to be able to click on the blank parts and fire clickFunc()