# trouble accessing tr id via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is a follow up to the question at [variable length <td> IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23365930/variable-length-td-ie9/23367135?noredirect=1#23367135)

i'm using query 1.11.

the standard ways of accessing the id in the clicked on tr are not working:

```
 $(this).id
 $(this).attr('id');
```

and the others suggested in the docs.  They are all returning 'undefined'

i'm a bit confused as to how to get the id field properly.

my code:

```
 var tableString = '<table>';
 var tableArray=Array(10);

 for (i=0;i<tableArray.length; i++){
    if ((i % 2) == 0){
      tableArray[i] = '<tr disabled><td> some text </td><td> more text </td></tr>'
    } 
    else{
      tableArray[i] = '<tr id="' +i+ '" ><td> some text </td></tr>' 
    }

    tableString = tableString + tableArray[i];     
 }

 tableString = tableString + '</table>';
 jQuery('#tableDiv').append(tableString); 



 $('tr').attr('class','clicked');

 $('tr').click(function(){

     //this is where i want to get the id of the tr that was clicked

 });
```

Comment: Please show some HTML. It could be a click is triggered on a `td` instead of the `tr`.

Comment: `$(this).id` is *not* a standard way, it's an error (it should be `this.id`).

Comment: Your table structure is invalid. All rows must have the same number of cells (or rather, span the same number of columns in total). Your table has two cells in every even row, and only one in odd rows.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol That's not a problem for the JS or the DOM; the missing table cells are just not rendered.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/evMB2/1/ (only on trs where you actually set an id)

Comment: please prepare a fiddle